# C# forms, scrolling panel is not displaying

Tags: c#, graphics

I've been browsing internet for a long time, but I'm still confused...
I'm trying to add scrollbars to my panel, so I can view it... I'm getting this:

[image]

I have `autoScroll` set to `true`. Every time the user sets a new height and width, the height and width of a panel are changed - not sure if that doesn't cause trouble...

Any advice? Thanks in advice!

Comment: Well, that works but now the panel no longer fits the form.  You'd have to set the *form's* AutoScroll property to True.  Channeling what you really want to do, set the panel's AutoScrollMinSize property instead.  Now the panel gets the scrollbars when you make the grid too big to fit the panel.  Don't forget to use the AutoScrollPosition property when you paint the grid, pass it to e.Graphics.TranslateTransform().

Comment: Hmm, the AutoScrollMinSize is doing opposite thing - when grid fits in, the scrollbars are displayed, on the other hand, when grid is bigger they dissaperar... How do i pass AutoScrollPosition property to e.Graphics.TranslateTransform()? `protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(this.AutoScrollPosition.X, this.AutoScrollPosition.Y);
        }`...? im newbie, please dont hate me for theese dumb questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should drop a new `Panel` control on to you form to act as a "Scroll container".  It should have the same location and width and height as your picture box does now.  Set AutoScroll to true.  Then put your picture box *inside* that Panel.  As the picturebox grows and shrinks inside the panel the panel will get scroll bars to allow its contents (the picture box) to be scrolled.

The key is the nested controls, one to act as the "window on to the content" and the other to be the actual scrolled content.

---

**edit**

I just noticed you are drawing to a panel directly.  Same idea, just put your drawing Panel inside an AutoScroll panel.